# How to pass a pointer array to a function as pass by reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, pass-by-reference

How to pass a pointer array to a function as pass by reference?
I am passing a dynamic array to a function which is working correct within the function but i am unable to pass the pointer array as pass by reference.
I know that array is passed by default as pass by reference.
Thanks

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void printArray(int *arr, int SIZE){
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
void addData(int *arr, int &SIZE, int data){
    int *temp = new int[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        arr[i] = i;
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }
    printArray(temp, SIZE); //Output is: 0 1 2 3 4
    printArray(arr, SIZE);  //Output is: 0 1 2 3 4
    delete arr;
    arr = NULL;

    arr = new int[SIZE+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    arr[SIZE] = data;
    SIZE++;
    printArray(arr, SIZE);  //Output is: 0 1 2 3 4 5
    delete temp;
    temp = NULL;
}
int main(){
    int SIZE = 5;
    int *arr = new int[SIZE];
    addData(arr, SIZE, 5);  //Extend the array by one index to insert data
    printArray(arr, SIZE);  //Output is: Some garbage values but Output should be: 0 1 2 3 4 5

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Since you know an array is passed by reference by default, I don't understand what you might be asking.  What do you want to do *instead* of pass an array by reference?

Comment: You want to pass a pointer by reference. Pass the pointer by reference. `int * & arr`

Comment: You can use [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of arrays and their sizes. Use [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) to add data to a `vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `int *arr = new int[SIZE];` you have allocated memory to store `SIZE` of `int` and `arr` is pointing to this memory.

Inside `addData` function you call `arr = new int[SIZE+1];` expecting `arr` to be now pointing to a memory filled with new values when the function returns. However when `int *arr` is passed to `void addData(int *arr, int &SIZE, int data)` it gets **copied**. The pointer variable `arr` has the same value as an outer variable but they are referencing different places. After `arr = new int[SIZE+1];` inner variable no longer points to the same place as an outer one.

When you call `printArray` your outer `arr` will have the same garbage as it had when you called `int *arr = new int[SIZE];`.

You can accept `arr` argument by reference like `void addData(int* &arr, int &SIZE, int data)` to fix the problem. This will make sure that inner variable will be stored in the same place as an outer one persisting changes.

You might be confused about the fact that you actually pass a pointer and observing no changes persistence. The changes are actually persisted for the array elements. For example if you write `arr[0] = 2` in the function those changes will be present after function ends. But changes with the pointer variable itself are not persisted.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Function header should be

```
void addData(int &*arr, int &SIZE, int data)
```

Comment: Right idea. Might want to reverse the `*` and `&` though